# RegExp: why [^0-9-] != [\D-]?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regexp to remove all not digits and not dash ('-'). `new RegExp('[^0-9-]')` seems works but `new RegExp('[\\D-]')` remove dash also. Why is this different?

Comment: Because `[\D-]` is 'match any non-digit symbol OR dash', while `[^0-9-]` is 'match any symbol that's not digit or dash'.

Comment: `[\D-]` is equivalent to `[\D]`, as the `-` is already matched by `\D`.

Comment: Guys, it's JS: clearly `\\D` is how it's written in the string literal, not the regex one (it wouldn't match digits at all otherwise). The difference is worth to be mentioned, though. )

Comment: @raina77ow: I don't normally use `new RegExp`, I use regex literals, so I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[^0-9-]` is "anything that is NOT a digit, or is NOT a dash
`[\D-]` is "anythign that is NOT a digit, or IS a dash

the `^` inverts the entire `[]` character class, so on your `\D` version, there's no inversion, so a `-` is a legitimate match.

Comment: Isn't `[\\D-]` anything that is a ``\`` a `D` or a `-`? Maybe a typo in the question though or he copied it from a string literal. Assuming `\D`, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no negation in front of the dash in the second one. The `\D` (there should only be one backslash really) means 'all not-digits', the dash means a dash.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have interpreted the meaning of your second regex wrong.

The `^` at the beginning of the character class `[^0-9-]` matches all characters specified in it, specifically anything thats not `0-9` and not `-`. Whereas `[\D-]` matches anything thats not a digit and is a `-`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `^` in a character class (`[]`), it means "NOT anything in this class".  `\D` is just a special sequence that means "anything that's not a digit".

So:

`[^0-9-]` matches anything that isn't a digit or a `-`.

`[\D-]` means "any non-digit character (or a `-`, which is *already* a non-digit).  There is no need for the `[]` here, this is the same as just `\D` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

`\D` is simple shorthand for `^0-9`